# Magento 1.9 Mage, execute javascript command when customer successfully registers

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I'm trying to execute a java-script command when the customer successfully registers an account, I tried the following, but the java-script command doesn't get executed.[image: Used code]

Does somebody now how I can achieve this? Thank you in advance.

**[EDIT]**
I actually fixed it myself, I wanted to send some customer data to the html page via javascript. If you want to achieve this, please read my answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento SE, feel free to check out this post on how to ask a question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . 
Please provide more information such as what do you want to do exactly ? Redirect your customer ? Please explain what your final code is supposed to do ?

Comment: If you trace the code when a customer is registered successfully, you'll see that it will be redirect to a URL `$this->_redirectSuccess($url);` where $url is by default `customer/account/index` or the URL param `success_url`, see `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action ::_redirectSuccess()`. So, in order to execute your js,  you'll need to find a way to always redirect to the page where you have your js embedded. You can do this by hard-setting the `success_url`.

Answer (score 2):

After some more digging, and thanks to the answers from kiatng and lalit mohan, I found the answer.

I wanted to list all customer details to the page via javascript.

In the mage.php file, located at Magento\apps\magento\htdocs\app:

```
 public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    //Custom code, this is being executed when the customer succesfully registers
    if($name == "customer_register_success")
    {
        $customer = $data['customer'];
        $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId())->getData();

        $out = "";
        foreach( $customerData as $key => $value ) {
            //this prevents the password hash to be show in the session  
            if(!$key == "password_hash")
            {
                $out .= "|" . $key . ':' . $value;
            }
        }

        //Put customer vallues in the sessions
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["data"] = $out;
    }

  //Logging to htdocs/var/log/system.log
  Mage::log('Event fired:  ' . $name . "__" . $data);

  //Default code (this was already there)
  Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
  $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
  Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
  return $result;

}
```

Then in your javascript:

```
var customerdata = "<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION["data"]; ?>";
```

This will output all customer data to a string.

Comment: Did you add the js code in the same php file?

Answer (score 1):

you can run profiler to debug problem  by edit temporarily  Mage.php file. so you can output of all events for particular request..
File: app/Mage.php

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Mage::log('Event: ' . $name); //not using Mage::log, as 
    //file_put_contents('/tmp/test.log','Dispatching '. $name. "\n",FILE_APPEND); //poor man's log
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute your js, you'll need to find a way to always redirect to the page where you have your js embedded. You can do this by hard-setting the *success_url*. One way to do this is to listen to the event *customer_success_event*, as indicated in your attached image. After you have set this up, then the code is quite simple:

```
public funstion setCustomerRegisterSuccessUrl($observer)
{
    $successUrl = Mage::getUrl('your_module/your_controller/your_action');
    $controller = $observer->getEvent()->getAccountController();
    $controller->getRequest()->setParam('success_url', $successUrl);
}
```